# Flash Error #1034: Type Coercion failed when running with Flash Develop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flashdevelop, coercion

I have compiled an SWC and am using it in a flashdevelop project.

When I compile the project all is fine, but when I run/debug the project I get:

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@43e3f99 to fl.controls.Button.
```

The following line is causing the fault:

```
public var loginPanel:loginControl  = new loginControl();
```

LoginControlView is the movieclip name.
loginControlView is the asset name.
and there is a class called loginControl that extends loginControlView

The LoginControlView movieclip contains 2 textboxes and a button (fl.controls)

The project runs fine if I compile/run/debug from the Flash IDE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you remove the button from the LoginControlView movieclip? Are there any other errors displayed or does it work fine?

Comment: @Maurycy I get another similar error regarding the fl.controls.TextInput

Comment: Hmm, have you tried compiling this under Flex/Flash Builder?

Comment: Does flash develop not use the flex compiler?? the line 'Using the Flex Compiler Shell' in the flexdev output window suggests so!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Included in my classpaths was a path to the fl.controls folder of the flash install. But the fl.controls where also being exported with my SWC. 
I assume having two definitions of the same class was causing the problem, because when I removed the classpath all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

as you probably know, fl.controls package contains components for Flash Professional CS5 and earlier which *can* be used in Flash Develop by bundling the components in a .swc:  [How do I use an Adobe control from fl.controls.* in FlashDevelop?](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=F.A.Q#How_do_I_use_an_Adobe_control_from_fl.controls..2A_in_FlashDevelop.3F)

since your project compiles in Flash Professional without error the problem must lie within the exported fl.controls.* .swc.

instead of using an fl.contros.* .swc, since you're using Flash Develop, you could use the [spark.controls package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/package-detail.html) or [mx.controls package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/package-detail.html) from the Flex 4.1 SDK.  both packages include a Button and TextInput classes.

Comment: Hi, I already have the fl.contorls UI components exported to a seperate SWC. I can see theem when I browse the SWC package in FlashDevelop